# Firestore DeadlineExceeded exception for big collections

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read bigger collections from Google Firestore for testing and archiving purposes. I'm hitting some interesting errors when I try to get all documents from collections with more than 6k documents in them.

## Naive Python solution

My first try was using the Python `google-cloud-firestore` (version 0.30.0) library.

```py
source_client = firestore.Client()
source = source_client.collection(collection)
source_data = source.get()

counter = 0
for f in source_data:
    app.logger.info(f.id)
    counter += 1
    if counter % 100 == 0:
        app.logger.info('%s %d', datetime.now(), counter)

    app.logger.info('%s Finally read all %d documents', datetime.now(), counter)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
INFO:flask.app:2018-11-08 09:49:03.923795 6400  
INFO:flask.app:2018-11-08 09:49:04.115410 6500  
... 
INFO:flask.app:2018-11-08 09:49:03.923795 6400
INFO:flask.app:2018-11-08 09:49:04.115410 6500
WARNING:flask.app:2018-11-08 09:49:04.128478 copy brocken by exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/firestore/transfertool/main.py", line 142, in transfer
    count_collection(source_collection)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/firestore/transfertool/main.py", line 94, in count_collection
    for f in source_collection.offset(1000).get():
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/query.py", line 588, in get
    for index, response_pb in enumerate(response_iterator):
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 83, in next
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    # Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

Which seems to be caused by a quota. Even if I cannot see it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). It seems to be time based because when I run with small sleeps in between elements I get less throughput and get the exception after ~50s.

## Paging with Python

For exactly this problem there is a paging part in this library. As my application should not care about what kind of data I try to transfer I cannot use the `start_after` interface but there is still an offset interface with which I can at least read in batches.

```py
for f in source_collection.offset(last_read_offset).get():
```

Which gives me correct results as long as the `last_read_offset` is below 1001. If I start with an offset of 1000 I can get results until I get the `google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded exception` from above. But when I start with something bigger I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/firestore/transfertool/main.py", line 144, in transfer
    count_collection(source_collection)
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/firestore/transfertool/main.py", line 94, in count_collection
    for f in source_collection.offset(1001).get():
  File "/home/carsten/projects/transfertool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/query.py", line 599, in get
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unexpected server response. All responses other than the first must contain a document. The response at index 1 was
read_time {
  seconds: 1541668338
  nanos: 420813000
}
skipped_results: 1
```

Looking at the library code it seems that the backend is sending a message which is interpreted as invalid.

## Retry via node.js

Okay maybe my code or the Python client library is bugged. Let's try with node.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

var db = admin.firestore();
admin.firestore().settings( { timestampsInSnapshots: true })
var counter = 0

console.log('Read collection')
db.collection(collection).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            counter++;
        });
        console.log(counter)
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.log(error)
});
```

Which does the same as the python library even if the timeout is much more clearly 60s.

```
[2018-11-09T08:36:30.992Z] App listening on port 8080
[2018-11-09T08:36:30.993Z] Press Ctrl+C to quit.
[2018-11-09T08:36:37.390Z] Read collection
[2018-11-09T08:37:37.406Z] { Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/carsten/projects/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/carsten/projects/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:235:26)
    at ClientReadableStream._readsDone (/home/carsten/projects/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:201:8)
    at /home/carsten/projects/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:679:15
  code: 4,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'Deadline Exceeded' }
```

Has anyone similar experiences or a good hint how to continue?

PS: The `exportDocument` / `importDocument` interface is not enough as we sometimes have to adjust the data after reading. And I have no clue what kind of format Firestore is exporting to Google Cloud Storage or how to transform it.

## Edit: golang

And for the heck of it i tried the golang api.

```
log.Println("Collecting data")
snapshotIter := client.Collection(collection.(string)).Documents(ctx)
defer snapshotIter.Stop()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

i := 0

for {
    _, err := snapshotIter.Next()

    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if i % 100 == 0{
        log.Println(i)
    }
    i++
}

log.Println("Done")
```

Which runs into the same timeout as expected.

```
2018/11/12 15:01:20 Collecting data
2018/11/12 15:01:21 0
2018/11/12 15:01:21 100
2018/11/12 15:01:21 200
2018/11/12 15:01:21 300
2018/11/12 15:01:21 400
2018/11/12 15:01:22 500
2018/11/12 15:01:22 600
2018/11/12 15:01:22 700
....
2018/11/12 15:02:22 29800
2018/11/12 15:02:23 29900
2018/11/12 15:02:23 rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
```

But in addition the offset is working fine:

```
snapshotIter := client.Collection(collection.(string)).Offset(30000).Documents(ctx)
```

Comment: You could log an issue with the Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some help from the firebase support team we were able to figure out that there is indeed a bug with the python client api. There is a bugfix coming in one of the next releases. Most likely it will enable the python library to sort by documentid and therefore use `start_after()`.

Up until then you have two possible solutions:

1. use another field to sort on and use `start_after()`
2. use the node.js library with paging like:

```
var db = admin.firestore();
admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
function readNextPage(lastReadDoc) {
  let query = db
    .collection(collection)
    .orderBy(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
    .limit(100);
}
```

Comment: please review again: function read NextPage(lastReadDoc) ... where lastReadDoc parameter supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error just getting the entire collection. It was not even that big of a collection but I guess the documents in the collection are large. I did a paginated update. This was a node firebase function:

```
let lastReadDoc = false;


let lastDoc: string = '';
  const limitRecordCount = 10;
  do {
    await db
      .collection('something/' + somethingId + '/somethingcollection')
      .orderBy('id')
      .limit(limitRecordCount)
      .startAfter(lastDoc)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot: any) => {
        let counter = 0;
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc: any) => {
          const docData = doc.data();
          if (lastDoc !== docData.id) {
            lastDoc = docData.id;
            counter = counter + 1;
          }
          // ***********************
          // business logic per doc here
          // ***********************
        });
        if (counter < limitRecordCount) {
          lastReadDoc = true;
        }
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        lastReadDoc = true;
        console.log('Error getting booking documents', err);
      });
  } while (lastReadDoc === false);
```